# Can clicks from 1 view be passed "through" to another view?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I have a window that contains 2 separate views.   View A and view B.

View B is a transparent view so what you are seeing is actually View A on the screen.  Is there any ways to make clicks made on the screen (which goto View B since its on top) to actually act on View A?

View B is NOT a child view of view A.  They are both child views of the main Window.

*** Caveat here is that I still would need to be able to register any dragging events on View B.  I simply want the 'click' events to pass through**

View A is going to be the main screen of what the user is interacting with and View B is a draggable off-screen menu resting on a transparent background that is partially on the screen so the user can grab it and drag it into the screen

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a property you're looking for that can handle this, it is

```
touchEnabled: false
```

If you put that on your transparant view it should not trigger any click event, but the view below it should.

Comment: Wow, thx rene that did answer my question!  But I'm realizing my question was not descriptive enough.   I am actually making View B a draggable menu, so I do need clicks to pass through but dragging should still be allowed, which touchEnabled does not allow

Comment: in that case, how does the user know it drags the transparent view? What is the goal? :)

Comment: an off screen left menu.  The user knows that if you drag your finger somewhere from the left 1/3 of the screen towards the right a menu appears, something like this: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/ca0eac4614356859480b561c89d9cd86fd0f0d91/68747470733a2f2f646c2e64726f70626f7875736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f752f39393635373834352f736964654d656e752e676966